# onclick is not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery

I am working on development of a web application which is multi device compatible. I have used .onClick event of jquery to open modal box, menu, etc.
Its doing good on Android but on iPhone it needs to tap two times then it start functioning.

Please if anyone can help me to make it on singe tap.

Below is my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
                $(".slideMenu").click((function() {
            var i = 0;
            return function() {
                $(".sideMenu").animate({
                    left: (++i % 2 && i!== -180) ? 0 : -180
                }, 200);
                }
            })());
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried touchstart event instead of click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "click" on the iOS devices.   You would need to bind to touchstart.  If you are also needing to address the click as well then something like this should work.

```
$(function(){
            $(".slideMenu").on('click touchstart', function() {
        var i = 0;
        return function() {
            $(".sideMenu").animate({
                left: (++i % 2 && i!== -180) ? 0 : -180
            }, 200);
            }
        })());
    });
```

Here is a list of [iOS event types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5)